# Set Oracle 10g database connection timeout in Java

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, timeout

I tried to set a connection timeout with the following code:

```
public class ConnectionTimeout {  
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String entry = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxx:1521:xxx";
    Connection con=null;

    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

    DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(1);        
    con=DriverManager.getConnection(entry,"username","password");    

    Statement s=con.createStatement();    
    s.execute("select 1 from dual");    
    s.close();

    con.close();
  }
}
```

The instance `xxx` is not existing. But I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: E/A-Exception: Socket is not connected
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:255)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:387)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:439)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at my.package.connection.timeout.ConnectionTimeout.main(ConnectionTimeout.java:22)
```

How I can implement a timeout to an not existing or available Oracle database instance?

**Edit:**
If I set the `DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(30);` to 30 second, the exception happens so fast as before!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(1);` sets the maximum time in **seconds** for the driver to wait while connecting to the database. In your case, it's set to 1.

To have no limit, set `setLoginTimeout(0)` where `0` means no limit.

I hope this helps.

---

**Update** if your instance `xxx` doesn't exists, how would you expect your Oracle Driver to connect to the database? It won't make any difference how long you set your `loginTimeout` there's not "host" to connect to.

Comment: That is not was I mean. I want a small timeout for trying to etablish a connection. I'm confusing about when I set the timeout to 30 seconds! With 1 and 30 secondes, the exception comes immediately. Or is that OK in my test code?

Comment: @Tim Krueger, see updated post. That's why the response is immediate, there's no host.

Answer (score 0):

Because, in Java doc, it shows: timeout in seconds, but in the implementation of JDBC Oracle, it is milliseconds.

You can try using a measure of milliseconds.

Comment: Is this correct? I tried connecting with the timeout set to 1 in a loop, and never got a timeout. If it would be 1 millisecond, that would surprise me.